# 記号が多用される質問タイトルのググラビリティを向上させるには？

Tags: 討議, サポート, 質問の仕方, タイトル

プログラミングの話題を扱う関係上、スタック・オーバーフローでは質問の概要を示すタイトルに、記号が使用される場面が多くあります。しかし、そういった記号は**検索エンジンで無視されてしまう**ことが多く、ググラビリティが高いとはいえません。

この問題への対処法として、記号や式などを一般的に認知されている、またはリファレンスに記述されている**名称へ置き換える**方法があります。その一方で、それによってかえってタイトルが冗長になり、ググラビリティが低くなってしまうこともあると思います。

記号が多用される質問タイトルにおいて、どのような方法でググラビリティを向上させられますか？

---

これは補足ですが、本質問に至るきっかけとして、次の質問タイトルのググラビリティを高められないか、と悩んだ経緯があります。当該質問の記号を単純に名称で置き換えたとしても、タイトルが検索する際になかなか辿り着けない程度に冗長になり、ググラビリティは大して変わらないのでは、と感じています。

- [1/0 + 1 と 1./0 + 1 の演算結果が異なるのはなぜ？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/70901/32986)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

タイトルへ説明を簡潔に入れられそうな場合はそうしても良いですが、無理にそうする必要は無いでしょう。ググラビリティが低そうでも一発で中身の分かりやすいタイトルの方が便利そうです。この場合は、質問文を改善するのが良いのではないかと推測しています。

具体的には、記号に関して検索したくなった人が何回か試行錯誤して検索する中で、そのどれかに引っかかるようなキーワードを質問文にまぶしておくと、より便利になりそうではないでしょうか。

そのための自分なりの工夫として、質問文の中に検索エンジンが拾ってくれそうな検索ワードを意図的に仕込むことが時々あります。たとえば過去に「[Ruby の ||= 演算子とは？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/42780/19110)」という質問で `||=` のことを「OR とイコールを合わせたような、パイプ2本とイコールから成る演算子」と表現しました。

今回の「1/0 + 1 と 1./0 + 1 の演算結果が異なるのはなぜ？」については、実際に困っていた挙動に注目すると多少は検索しやすくなるかもしれません。つまり、この挙動で困ったのは割り算よりも足し算が優先されてしまっているように見えたという点ですので、このことについてしっかり書かれていれば多少は検索されやすくなるのではないかな、と考えています。

このような感じで、タイトルに記号が含まれていて、しかも言い換えも難しいような場合は、質問文を工夫して検索性を上げられないかな、と思っています。ただ、実際に SEO を計測した訳ではないので、すべて推測ではありますが……。

（そもそも Google の検索順位をどこまで頑張って上げる必要があるのか問題もあります。SOja の中の検索で分かるようになっていれば充分では、説……。）